# ELB health checks for freshly launched EC2 instances not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I'm trying to manually set up a load balanced environment using EC2. My instances are reachable via SSH and ping. However, as soon as I put them inside a load balancer, the instances are not able to pass the load balancer's health checks.

- I've tried following the [Troubleshooting Elastic Load Balancing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html) guide. Connecting to any instance via telnet from another instance inside the same VPC does not work.
- Executing `telnet localhost 25` inside an instance seems to work.
- The instances run Amazon Linux.
- The health check happens via TCP to port 80.
- The load balancer and the instances are in the same security group.
- I've already loosened up all security group settings and allowed communication via all ports, all members of all groups are able to ssh / ping each other.
- The problems appear right after launch, no matter if I've set up the instances with the software I want them to run or left them untouched.

What else should I try? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your web server running on your instance? Can you confirm that the instance responds with status code 200 on port 80 if you connect to it directly using a web browser or curl?

Comment: Thanks. I got it working by directing the health check to port 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working by directing the health check to port 22.