# Elastic Beanstalk environment and security group config for ELB health checker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, configuration, elastic-beanstalk, healthcheck

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment that I can't get Health Checks to work on.

Here's my Elastic Beanstalk's Load Balancer configuration:
[image]

My healthcheck URL is */status/*

My EC2 security group (screenshot below) allows all HTTP traffic (for debug purposes). sg-0cf154fc56a3cad5f is the Load Balancer's security group.
[image]

The Load Balancer security group just allows HTTP and HTTPS access from my current IP address.

I'm able to access my site just fine when I go to https: //www.website.com
and I receive a status 200 when I go to https: //www.website.com/status/ from my browser.

The access logs for my environment show a 400 response for requests from the ELB-HealthChecker. The one 200 response is from when I went to the site in my browser.
[image]

- I've tried adding HTTP and HTTPS access from 0.0.0.0/0 to my Load
  Balancer's security group without any luck.
- I've also tried directing the healthchecks to [port 22](https://serverfault.com/questions/705632/elb-health-checks-for-freshly-launched-ec2-instances-not-working).
- All my security groups are within the same VPC.

What am I missing from my config that will allow the eb-healthchecker to reach my instances?